# What does System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.CanReduce property mean?

Tags: linq, linq-expressions, custom-linq-providers

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.canreduce%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and its name implying, it can be inferred that the value of the `CanReduce` property must be set to true for all expressions that can further be decomposed into smaller expressions, and vice-versa.

But upon closer observation, this inference appears not to hold true in all cases. Take the case of `LambdaExpression`, which certainly is a composite unit. But the `LambdaExpression` class, deriving directly from the `Expression` class, does not override the `CanReduce` property. The `Expression` class defines the `CanReduce` property as virtual with an implementation that returns `false`, thus implying that a lambda expression is not further reducible, which is not true.

What then is the real meaning of this property?

Comment: For example, compound assignment `a+=b` can be reduced to `a=a+b`.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Is the meaning restricted to just these operators (I forget what they're called)?

Comment: I does not dig that deep into `System.Linq.Expressions`, to say is it true or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, nevertheless. I think I found something that might be useful in this case, over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2044367/303685

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET 4.0: What does Expression.Reduce() do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038759/net-4-0-what-does-expression-reduce-do) (I know, you are asking about `CanReduce`, not `Reduce`. However if you understand what the latter does, you will be a very large step closer to understanding the former.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're reading the documentation wrong. "Reducing" here doesn't mean decomposing into multiple simpler expressions, it means transforming into a single expression that uses more basic operations. For example, consider the following `ListInitExpression` (using C#-like syntax):

```
new List<int> { 1, new Random().Next() }
```

Calling `CanReduce` on this expression will return `true`. And calling `Reduce()` will return:

```
{
    Param_0 = new List<int>();
    Param_0.Add(1);
    Param_0.Add(new Random().Next());
    return Param_0;
}
```

It's not clear to me what should `Reduce()` on a `LambdaExpression` return, so it makes sense to me that it's not reducible.

Answer (score 5):

I posted a longer answer here with more details: [What does Expression.Reduce() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038759/net-4-0-what-does-expression-reduce-do?lq=1), but the short form is that the out-of-box .NET behavior seems to only reduce the following scenarios:

- Compound assignment e.g. `x += 4`
- Pre/post increment/decrement e.g. `x++`, `--y`
- Member and list initialization e.g. `new List<int>() { 4, 5 }`, `new Thing() { Prop1 = 4, Prop2 = 5 }`

Everything else is left as-is. I didn't see any evidence for or against dead expression culling as part of a reduce operation (e.g. an empty BlockExpression won't get removed from an expression tree during Reduce() calls).

Comment: Beautiful, practical and useful, the way you answer it. Thank you.